# Can I check if computer in a lan is still booting, or completely turned off?

Tags: php, networking

I am developing a simple software suite that has 2 components:

- A client application written in delphi running on a machine
- A php application running on a server, but still in the lan

The server php script can send a tcp packet to the client application to stop or restart the client computer.

When the client computer is turned off, the server php script can also send a magic packet to wake up the client computer.

I know if the client machine is running, because the client application periodically contacts the server php script, but what I want to know is:

If I issue a restart command, is there a way to check whether the client computer is still booting up, or something went wrong and it have shut down completely?

So basically I want something like pinging a still booting up computer to check if it is "alive and doing it's thing".

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. The computer cannot respond to any network requests (inc. ping) until network services are loaded as part of boot process. as part of login process on some OS.